# How to find out the source code of the earliest release/version?

Tags: open-source, version-control, source-code

Reading source code of the early release/version is very helpful for beginner to digest complex project. There is less line of code and learner can see the progression of the project.

However, finding those early version is not easy. Those early work may be deemed as "useless" and not get publish online or include in version control system.

For example,
python celery only has v2.1.1 as its earliest tag on Github

So what's your secret trick to find out those early work?

Comment: I don't have a secret trick.  I use what is available to me.  There isn't enough value in early code to go to the trouble of chasing down the original author to get it, if he even has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your example (python celery) I assume you are talking about `python` code/projects

If this is the case, then you can find what you looking for at [`pypi`](https://pypi.python.org).
e.g:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery/0.1.2.

Just download the source file, and you will have all the code.

To find out what versions are available on `pypi` you can use the code from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39506335/635762)